# XSL transformation doesn't write namespace before elements

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to update the file content.xml in an odt file.
I want to obtain the same file content without spaces from elements and without line break.

I tried to use an xsl transormation with the Transformer object in Java, and it partly works.
For example, having a simple odt, which the content.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" office:version="1.2">
    <office:font-face-decls>
        <style:font-face style:name="Courier New" style:font-family-generic="modern" style:font-pitch="fixed" svg:font-family="'Courier New'" />
    </office:font-face-decls>
    <office:automatic-styles>

    </office:automatic-styles>
    <office:body>
        <office:text>
            <text:p text:style-name="Title">TODO supply a title</text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="Text_20_body">TODO write content</text:p>
            <text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_1" text:outline-level="1">My First Heading</text:h>
            <text:p text:style-name="First_20_paragraph">My first paragraph.</text:p>
        </office:text>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

I wrote this xsl file to remove all line breaks, blank spaces between elements, so I want obtain the same XML content serialize in one line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
                xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
                xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
                xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
                xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
                xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
                xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" 
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
                xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" 
                xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" 
                xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" 
                xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" 
                xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" 
                xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" 
                xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" 
                xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" 
                xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" 
                xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" 
                xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" 
                xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
                xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
                extension-element-prefixes="office style text"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-15" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I used indent="no" and strip-space elements="*" to have no identation, but now my problem is the namespaces.
The XML which I obtain using this xsl is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?><document-content xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" office:version="1.2"><font-face-decls><font-face style:font-family-generic="modern" style:font-pitch="fixed" style:name="Courier New" svg:font-family="'Courier New'"/></font-face-decls><automatic-styles/><body><text><p text:style-name="Title">TODO supply a title</p><p text:style-name="Text_20_body">TODO write content</p><h text:outline-level="1" text:style-name="Heading_20_1">My First Heading</h><p text:style-name="First_20_paragraph">My first paragraph.</p></text></body></document-content>
```

It's in one line, as I want, but the elements has no namespace prefix.
Note that it doesn't happen with attributes, which have correct namespaces.

In the xsl I specified to match node, comment and attributes, the namespaces in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element and the extension-element-prefixes passing the list of allowed namespaces.
If I remove the extension-element-prefixes nothing change.

The Java code which use the Transformer object is the following:

```
 public void serializeXML(String filePath, String destinationPath) throws Exception {
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    doc.normalizeDocument();

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    InputStream is = XMLSerializer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("identer.xsl");

    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(is));

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
    transformer.transform(domSource, sr);

    Result result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath)));

    transformer.transform(domSource, result);

    LOGGER.info(sw.toString());
}
```

I declare the Transformer object, passing to it the inputStream of the xsl file.
I don't set any properties because I declare all (in my opinion) is necessary in the xsl file, and after that I tranform the document, saving the result in a file and printing it with a logger.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you setup/configure your Transformer ?

Comment: Your code works correctly using this online transformer: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWD works fine for me. As for extension-element-prefixes, that attribute is not relevant in any way for namespaces to be copied, it merely indicates elements in a namespace to be treated as extension element instructions.

Comment: @robert To configure the Transformer I used this instructions:
`InputStream is = XMLSerializer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("identer.xsl");
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(is));StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
transformer.transform(domSource, sr);
Result result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath)));
transformer.transform(domSource, result);`.
I don't use the setOutputProperty method because the indent and encoding are specified in xsl file.

Comment: @robert I updated the post, adding the Java code used to create the Transformer. Reading the anwers to my question I note that with the online xsl transformers, the xsl works correctly. It's possible that the error is due to an wrong usage of Transformer?

Comment: @MilioliLuca What are the actual implementations of your Transformer? Check transformerFactory.newTransformer(...).getClass().getName() if you are not sure.

Comment: @robert I revides the code about the Transformer usage.
See the answer to the question.
Your answer it was helpfull to reconsider the Java code wich use the Transformer and xsl file.
Thank you.
+1 to your answers to underline the Transformer usage revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, thanks to the users who answer to my question.

I revised my code, so the xsl now is:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-15" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And then I simplified the Java code which use the Transformer:

```
 public void serializeXML(String filePath, String destinationPath) throws Exception {

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream is = XMLSerializer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("identer.xsl");
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(is);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File(filePath));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File(destinationPath)));

    }
```